# How to trigger Synapse Pipeline by HTTP call from Power Apps?

Tags: azure-synapse, powerapps

Is it possible to make REST API call from Power Apps (+automate) so that Synapse Pipeline get triggered? (ADF connector can be found, but not Synapse)

Does Synapse pipeline it self have URL to be called or how does it work?

How to make secure that no one else than PowerApps or ADF developer can trigger the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below REST API to achieve your requirement.

```
https://<synapse_workspace_name>.dev.azuresynapse.net/pipelines/<pipeline_name>/createRun?api-version=2020-12-01
```

Use HTTP POST action to call the above API.

To do that we need authorization. Create an App registration with Secret (Service principal) and add it to the synapse access control like below.

[image]

After this, use `Client ID`, `Tenant ID` and `Secret value` in the HTTP POST action.

[image]

Here my workspace name is `rakeshsynapse` and pipeline name is `mypipeline`.

**Result pipeline run in synapse:**

[image]

It will be secure because it requires the Service principal credentials to call it.